Contact Key and Device ID
Is there a possibility of extracting all my contacts in SFMC that have a populated Contact Key and Device ID is not null? I want to export this list onto my FTP

I would suggest a mobile filtered list

I did the mobile filtered list but how do I export this list Daily through a automation?
